# Add outside stroke to the text with css

Tags: html, css, sass

How to add outside stroke for the text.
I tried with -webkit-text-stroke: 10px black; and text-shadow but my text becomes thinner, I want to have font size 24px.

```css
p {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #844733, 1px -1px 0 #844733, -1px 1px 0 #844733, 1px 1px 0 #844733;
  
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<p>my text</p>
```

here is the image ->   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xMgn.png

I wanted very thick stroke and only outlide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a pseudo element with identical text content to the main text and give the pseudo element the text-stroke. It was shown on [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/text-stroke-stuck-middle/#set-behind-trick).

```css
p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: relative
}
p:after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  -webkit-text-stroke: 6px #844733;
  color: #844733;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1
}
```

```html
<p data-text="my text">my text</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

@import "compass/css3";

-webkit-text-stroke: width of stroke;

this one is pretty smooth

Comment: I wanted with pure css